# Accessing package-private fields in Java

Tags: java, android, encapsulation

Poking around Android API sources. There's `FileDescriptor` with a data member `descriptor` with no access modifier:

```
int descriptor;
```

Then there's class `FileOutputStream` that constructs a new FileDescriptor and assigns to that field:

```
fd = new FileDescriptor();
fd.descriptor = fileSystem.open(...);
```

How is that compatible with the field access control model of Java? I thought package-private fields are not accessible from outside the declaring class, and there's no notion of friendship like in C++.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Basically, package-private can be accessed at the `class` and `package` levels:

From [the source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

```
Access Levels
Modifier    Class   Package  Subclass World
public         Y        Y       Y       Y
protected      Y        Y       Y       N
no modifier    Y        Y       N       N
private        Y        N       N       N
```

Comment: What constitutes a package in this context? All classes in namespace `java.io`? Or all classes in `java.io` in the same compilation unit?

Comment: The "namespace" `java.io` constitutes a package, so the breadth of `java.io` would have "package-level" access.

Comment: So `I`, the API consumer, can poke around that field if I declare a class in `java.io`? Sounds like a pretty wild breach of encapsulation to me.

Comment: [@Seva Alekseyev](http://stackoverflow.com/users/219159/seva-alekseyev): yes you can.

Comment: The Android build system will yell and scream and error out, though, if you try declaring anything in `java.*`.

Answer (score 1):

a Declaration with no modifier, like

> int descriptor;

Are package private, more commonly referred as DEFAULT are accessible within the package and not outside the package.
Any class inside the same package can access these but these are not visible outside package.

For more details please refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

```
Access Levels
Modifier        Class   Package     Subclass    World
public            Y         Y        Y            Y
protected         Y         Y          Y          N
no modifier       Y         Y          N          N
private           Y         N          N          N
```

Answer (score 0):

Package private field (and anything else) are just that: private within their package. This means that no other class can access the field (or other entity)  outside of the scope of the package. For more specific detail, refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).